# How to center align button in Semantic UI React?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

how can I center align a button in Semantic UI React
I have tried several approaches, using Grid, Grid Row, but no success

```
import {Segment, Button,Label,Sticky,Grid,Container} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const GeneralSupportSegment =() => (
    <Segment>
         <Label  ribbon color="blue"  size="large">Support</Label>
         <Button>contact us</Button>
    </Segment>
);

export default GeneralSupportSegment;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would be nice if you could share what you tried to do.

One solution might be:

```
<Segment>
  <Label ribbon color="blue" size="large">Support</Label>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Column textAlign="center">
      <Button>contact us</Button>
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid>
</Segment>
```

You can see it working here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/z2pkv0ro43

Comment: Is there not a simpler solution that doesn't require to add a grid?

Comment: The point is why it is not aligned center. We can center it by wrapping it with other things.

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me, without using Grid

```
<Segment>
    <Label ribbon color="blue" size="large">Support</Label>
    <Segment basic textAlign={"center"}>
        <Button style={{textAlign: "center"}}>contact us</Button>
    </Segment>
</Segment>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the code below to be a cleaner solution that doesn't require to add **Grid** from semantic-ui. The only thing was that I used the button within my register/sign up form. May not work for everyone.

What I did was add a

**className: 'signUpBtn'**

and then within my css file I added the

**display:flex**;

**justify-content:center;**

JSX:

```
<Form.Field className="signUpBtn" color="blue" control={Button}> Register </Form.Field>
```

CSS:

```
.signUpBtn {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution I have:

Previous code of icon inside a button(not aligned in the centre):

```
<Button>
    <Icon name="plus"/>
</Button>
```

Updated code(**icon aligned at center**):

```
<Button>
    <div>
        <Icon name="plus"/>
    </div>
</Button>
```